# Get element value and add them (parseFloat seems to fail)

Tags: javascript

I have the code above:

```
var element1=$("#element1").val(); 
//the element1 value is 12.60 
//html code for this element <input id="element1" value="12.60" />
element1=parseFloat(element1).toFixed(2);

var element2=$("#element2").text(); 
//the element2 value is 1.00 
//html code for this element <span id="element2">1.00</span>
element2=parseFloat(element2).toFixed(2);

var addthem=element1+element2;

console.log(addthem);
```

And of course I am expecting to see `13.60` but I get `12.601.00` (add the as string).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseFloat` is working fine, but then you're explicitly getting a string version of the values (via `toFixed`), and so `+` concatenates the strings. Only use `toFixed` at the point you want to convert the numbers to a string (for instance, to output to an element).

Comment: Your point is right.But what if i want to use toFixed and return a float number.In my case i have already 2 decimal point, but if i had 4 decimals i had to convert to float with 2 decimal points.

Comment: @ntan: You could always do `parseFloat(parseFloat(xxx).toFixed(2))` (I forget what guarantees the standard makes about whether `toFixed` does half-up rounding or just truncates; I think it does half-up rounding), but you might be better off explicitly rounding the numbers. Sadly, `Math.round` can only round to integer values, but it's easy enough to build on that to create floating-point rounding: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml

Answer (score 2):

A quick check with Firebug, shows that the toFixed() method returns a string in Firefox:

```
var f = 16.055;
console.log(typeof(f.toFixed(1)));
```

returns: `string`

Thus you should change the second last line to:

```
var addthem = parseFloat(element1) + parseFloat(element2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`toFixed()`, i believe, returns a String as its datatype.
The `+` operator you use in `var addthem=element1+element2;`  works as string concatenation, since `+` is overloaded in JavaScript. If any of the operands is a string, a string value is returned.